# AngularJS uploader module: how to access file url before upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm using angular file upload (https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API) and currently trying to access the uploaded file url before saving (so I can use it as a background image). I realize that you can easily create a thumbnail of the file, but I'm having issues accessing the url so I can use it as a background image (since I want to position the image and not scale it and show the whole image as thumbnail would do).

So I can access the image for a thumbnail:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in uploader.queue">
  <div ng-thumb="{ file: item._file, height: 202, width: 376 }"></div>
</div>
```

But this does not work (I'm assuming because item._file is the actual image and background-image requires a url)

```
<div ng-repeat="item in uploader.queue">
  <div class="row" ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{item._file}})'}"> 
</div>
```

Syntax wise, I know the ng-style is fine since I tried replaced the item._file above with a public url and the styling worked as expected. I also tried replacing item._file with item.url since url is a property of it and url is apparently null so that didn't work. Any ideas on how I can achieve this or alternate solutions?

Comment: Why dont you just upload the image first and set it as a background afterwards through your callbacks `.then()` funciton?

Comment: That would work but the image is being used for a "preview" modal before the user saves it

Comment: It looks like from the docs there are many callback functions that you can tap into.  Which have these have you tried, and what was the result?

Comment: onAfterAddingFile, tried accessing the keys in that object and url was one of them but when I return it - url is null